# jQuery UI autocomplete unexpected token ","(comma)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I use the `autocomplete` and it works on PC just fine. However, when I try to debug it on a mobile device, that is the error I am getting.

I have heard about `jQuery mobile`, is that a requirement if I want jQuery to work on mobile devices or not?

CODE(error on the 3rd line):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({addresses,
  minLength: 3,
  messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you give the code for the var `addresses` ?

Comment: does https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete solve the autocomplete problem?  Ask me for help if you need it, because I'm still working on it a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed key before adresses, Try this:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  source: addresses,
  minLength: 3,
  messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
  });
```

also there is no option messages in jQuery UI autocomplete see the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Man you are amazing!!! It works, I mean it is very dumb mistake, but it took me so much time of thinking if it is because I am not using `jquery mobile` etc... Thanks a lot.

Comment: But funny is that it works on desktop .. so there are some issues which mobile browser can't solve and desktop one can.